# How do I add another case when there is no prime number between a range(x != y)

Tags: c

**Below is the C code for printing prime numbers between intervals x and y (inclusive of x and y)**
Suppose when x is 2, y is 2 then i have added a statement for it in Line 1
Similarly, i want to present another statement like this but in this one x and y should not be equal for eg. x=8 , y=10. How should I do it?

**Test Case**

**Input 1**
2
11

**Output 1**
2 3 5 7 11

**Input 2**
3
-10

**Output 2**
Negative integers cannot be prime

**Input 3**
0
1

**Output 3**
There are no prime numbers in the range 0 to 1

**Input 4**
1
1

**Output 4**
There are no prime numbers in the range 1 to 1

**Input 5**
1
11

**Output 5**
2 3 5 7 11

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

void main()
{
    int num, x, y, i, count;
    scanf("%d\n%d", &x, &y);
    if (x<0 || y<0)
    {
        printf("\nNegative integers cannot be prime");
    }
    else if (x==y)
    {
        printf("\nThere are no prime numbers in the range %d to %d", x, y);  //Line1
    }
    else
    {
        for (num=x; num<=y; num++)
        {
            count=0;
            for(i=2; i<=num/2; i++)
            {
                if (num%i==0)
                {
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (count==0 && num!=1)
            printf("\n%d ", num);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not understand: in the case where x = 2 and y = 2, 2 is prime, right? So the `else if` branch is wrong.

Comment: There is no simple test for whether there are any primes in a given interval; you will have to check for them. Maybe keep a counter of the number of primes found, and if none are found in the interval, print the message.

Comment: Also, there is one prime in the interval [2, 2]. Your code says that there are none....

Comment: I have just added the cast cases. This is what I want to implement

Comment: You don't need to check for `(x==y)`. This will be handled for any given range anyway. Just introduce a flag that indicates wheter you found some prime during your loop and if this is still `false`, print your message.

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void main()
{
  int num, x, y, i, count;
  int primecounter = 0;

  scanf("%d\n%d", &x, &y);
  if (x < 0 || y < 0)
  {
    printf("\nNegative integers cannot be prime\n");
  }
  else
  {
    for (num = x; num <= y; num++)
    {
      count = 0;
      for (i = 2; i <= num / 2; i++)
      {
        if (num % i == 0)
        {
          count++;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (count == 0 && num != 1)
      {
        printf("\n%d ", num);
        primecounter++;
      }
    }

    if (primecounter == 0)
    {
      printf("There are no prime numbers in the range %d to %d\n", x, y);
    }
  }
}
```

We simply count the number of primes that have been printed, and if no primes have been printed, we display the error message `"There are no prime numbers in the range ...`.

And the test `if (x==y)` is obviously wrong, because e.g. the interval `5, 5` does contain exactly one prime, that is `5`.

There is still room for improvement though, for example naming your variables to something else that just `x` and `y`, declaring variables at scope (`for (int i = ...`) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I present you a modified code to handle the cases you asked.
A few things to note -

- There is no need to  handle the case `x==y` separately from third one.
- The primality testing is handled by a function `checkPrime`. It is changed slightly to perform in `O(sqrt(num))` rather than in `O(num)`.
- Your `count` in `main` variable  now has different use from that in your code. It counts the number of primes between `x` and `y` (inclusive).

Modified Code -

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int checkPrime(int num)
{
    if(num==1)
        return 0;
    int i,sq=(int)sqrt(num);
    for(i=2;i<=sq;i++)
        if(num%i==0)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int num, x, y, i, count;
    scanf("%d\n%d", &x, &y);

    // this  is to ensure that x<=y
    if(x>y)
    {
        int temp=x;
        x=y;
        y=temp;
    }

    if (x<0 || y<0)
    {
        printf("Negative integers cannot be prime\n");
    }
    else
    {
        count=0;
        for (num=x; num<=y; num++)
        {

            if(checkPrime(num)){
                count++;
                printf("%d ",num);
            }

        }
        if(count==0)
            printf("There are no prime numbers in the range %d to %d", x, y);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Question: why is  `for(i=2;i<=sqrt(num);i++)` potentially inefficient?

Comment: Yes, but __I__'m asking it.

Comment: No. Ask yourself this question: _how many times is `sqrt(num)` executed ?_

Comment: Okay so its about repeatedly calculating the same value.

Comment: Exactly. But calling `sqrt` once is OK and it's certainly better than your new solution. On the other hand your initial solution may be optimized anyway by a smart compiler.

Comment: Downvoter, please leave  a comment so that I can improve.